# Azure AKS Monitoring - custom dashboard resources

Tags: monitoring, azure-aks

I am trying to create a custom dashboard with some specific data for the AKS cluster. What i would like to do is assemble a dashboard with a graph of the RAM and CPU usage per selected controllers and nodes, and if possible number of restarts per pod. How can i create a custom graphs with the controllers average resource usage ?

Comment: go for it, whats the question?

Comment: You're right it wasn't clear enough. I modified it a bit.

Comment: Why don't you use Azure Container Monitor? It does this out of the box. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-overview

Comment: I'm using it. What i would like to achieve though is to make a standalone graph which to add into a custom dashboard with all the TREND MAX % (1 BAR = 15M) values for a Controller, which currently i can only access from their custom Metrics view.
https://pasteboard.co/I0c2De6.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click on "Logs" link on the left on your AKS cluster blade in Azure Portal (make sure you have Insights enabled by clicking on "Insights" first - if it is Ok, you'll see charts close to what you want otherwise, you'll see onboarding instructions).

Use the following query to chart CPU utilization (95th %-tile) for all containers in a given controller:

```
let endDateTime = now();
let startDateTime = ago(14d);
let trendBinSize = 1d;
let capacityCounterName = 'cpuLimitNanoCores';
let usageCounterName = 'cpuUsageNanoCores';
let clusterName = 'coin-test-i';
let controllerName = 'kube-svc-redirect';
KubePodInventory
| where TimeGenerated < endDateTime
| where TimeGenerated >= startDateTime
| where ClusterName == clusterName
| where ControllerName == controllerName
| extend InstanceName = strcat(ClusterId, '/', ContainerName), 
         ContainerName = strcat(controllerName, '/', tostring(split(ContainerName, '/')[1]))
| distinct Computer, InstanceName, ContainerName
| join hint.strategy=shuffle (
    Perf
    | where TimeGenerated < endDateTime
    | where TimeGenerated >= startDateTime
    | where ObjectName == 'K8SContainer'
    | where CounterName == capacityCounterName
    | summarize LimitValue = max(CounterValue) by Computer, InstanceName, bin(TimeGenerated, trendBinSize)
    | project Computer, InstanceName, LimitStartTime = TimeGenerated, LimitEndTime = TimeGenerated + trendBinSize, LimitValue
) on Computer, InstanceName
| join kind=inner hint.strategy=shuffle (
    Perf
    | where TimeGenerated < endDateTime + trendBinSize
    | where TimeGenerated >= startDateTime - trendBinSize
    | where ObjectName == 'K8SContainer'
    | where CounterName == usageCounterName
    | project Computer, InstanceName, UsageValue = CounterValue, TimeGenerated
) on Computer, InstanceName
| where TimeGenerated >= LimitStartTime and TimeGenerated < LimitEndTime
| project Computer, ContainerName, TimeGenerated, UsagePercent = UsageValue * 100.0 / LimitValue
| summarize P95 = percentile(UsagePercent, 95) by bin(TimeGenerated, trendBinSize) , ContainerName
| render timechart
```

Replace cluster name and controller name with the ones you want. You can also play with start/end time parameters, bin sizes, max/min/avg in place of 95th %-tile.

For memory metrics replace metric names with:

```
let capacityCounterName = 'memoryLimitBytes';
let usageCounterName = 'memoryRssBytes';
```

Comment: Thanks Vitaly , i'll give it a try.

Comment: I forgot to mention, sorry: once you have the query displaying what you want to see on the dashboard, click "pin" icon above and to the right of the result and it''ll show up on the dashboard of your choice

Comment: i changed 
let clusterName = 
let controllerName =
with the ones relevant to my cluster and i'm getting a syntax error. Cannot figure it out where exactly in the query.

Comment: Could you please email askcoin@microsoft.com and include your query as well as screenshot of the *query* as well as the *error* you're getting? We'll be able to help you fix your query syntax... Sometimes it is really sneaky... Single quotes changed to something else while copy-paste, etc... I checked the query above one more time just in case and it appears to work fine...

Comment: yep , sent ! Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you Vitaly, as you mentioned in the mail : 
| where TimeGenerated >= startDateTime – trendBinSize
should be   
 | where TimeGenerated >= startDateTime - trendBinSize
now it works !